# Match text between empty lines C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like

```
rrr
ttt

yyyy
zzz
cc

iii
o
```

I need to match blocks between empty lines. So, the result should be:

```
0.
rrr
ttt

1.
yyyy
zzz
cc

2.
iii
o
```

Tried

```
var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(text, @"([a-zA-Z]+\r\n)+");
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: try this: ([A-z]+\n)+

Comment: there needs to be an enter after that last o.  I always test regex here:http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this while reading the file :

```
// create a placeholder for processed lines
List<List<string>> _output = new List<List<string>>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(filePath)))
{
    int i = 0; // create indexer
    _output.Add(new List<string>()); // add new sequence
    _output.Last().Add(i.ToString() + "."); // insert sequence indexer
    string line = string.Empty;
    while( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        {
            i++;
            _output.Add(newList<string>());
            _output.Last().Add(i.ToString() + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            _output.Last().Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write this into a text file using :

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(filePath)))
{
    foreach(List<string> lines in _output)
    {
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

If that's not a file ( which was not specified ) but `string` instead, you can use `StringReader` instead of `StreamReader` and `StringWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`.

For everyone else that want to downvote because of "non-regex" answer or some other b....

[Make your comparison](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cDudIM)

Comment: This may be useful, but it does not use a regular expression.

Comment: Why would you want to use regex in this problem?

Comment: @ventiseis Why do you need to use regular expression when you can do this on the fly while reading the file? makes no sense to me.

Comment: @AnthonyC Don't know, I didn't ask the question. As Robin Mackenzie said: file reading isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie That's why you should read the whole answer not just the heading part. I've specified that you can use `StringReader` and `StringWriter` instead of `Stream`.

Answer (score 3):

*I just wanted to add some explanation:*

- `Regex(@"(.+((\r\n)|$))+")` is a little shorter and should match your text blocks as well  because:

  - `.+` matches everything but newlines
  - `(\r\n)|$)` matches a new line or the end of the string
  - `(.+((\r\n)|$))+` matches multiple non-empty lines
- instead of splitting and regrouping, you could simply use `text.Split(new[] { "\r\n\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Furthermore, there is this discussion about performance of regular expressions. I compared the answer of m.rogalski, the regular expression (precompiled), and the string.split solution with [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/), which is a common microbenchmark solution. Instead of writing the output to the console, I just put it into a list.

*Here are the benchmark results for the sample text*:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.1, OS=Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Processor=Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B970 2.30GHz, ProcessorCount=2
Frequency=2241012 Hz, Resolution=446.2270 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1586.0
  DefaultJob : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.6.1586.0

           Method |      Mean |    StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
 ---------------- |---------- |---------- |------- |---------- |
       TestRegExp | 5.1306 us | 0.0402 us | 1.1607 |   1.41 kB |
        TestLists | 1.1866 us | 0.0106 us | 0.3395 |     408 B |       
  TestStringSplit | 1.3574 us | 0.0103 us | 0.6971 |     784 B |
```

What can we observe?

- regexp is five times slower, requires ten times more memory
- string spliting requires more memory because it copies the string
- **the most efficient solution is implemented by using the stringreader**

Answer (score 1):

I would go for simple solution that yields groups:

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetGroups(IEnumerable<string> source)
    {
        var grouped = new List<string>();
        foreach(var el in source)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(el))
                grouped.Add(el);
            else if(grouped.Any())
            {
                yield return grouped;
                grouped = new List<string>();
            }
        }

        if(grouped.Any())
            yield return grouped;

    }
```

And the usage:

```
    var input = @"rrr
ttt

yyyy
zzz
cc

iii
o";


        var res = GetGroups(input.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()));
        foreach(var r in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",r));
        }
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xB87bZ

Comment: I would recommend using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` instead of `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` because if the line after `ttt` would be`  \r\n` instead of `\r\n` then your solution will fail.

Comment: True, I will change that

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use [nested groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/nested_groups):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

MatchCollection findings = new Regex(@"((.|(\n.))+)|((\n\n)((.|(\n.))+))").Matches(text);
for(int i = 0; i < findings.Count; i++) {
    int groupIndex = findings[i].Groups[1].Length > 0 ? 0 : 6;
    string match = findings[i].Groups[groupIndex].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(i+".");
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

You can test the speficied regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/YuB00L/1). The result is either in the group 1 or 6 (as seen in the code snippet above).

I don't know why the currently accepted answer is a non-regex solution ...

Comment: Currently accepted answer is working as intended what I cannot say about your solution. If you'll have space character in the "non visible" line, your match will [break](https://regex101.com/r/YuB00L/2).

Comment: Technically, I think that a line containing any characters is not an empty line. Even if they are spaces. An empty line is a '\n', preceded by zero other (non new line) characters. OP said "empty line", not "non visible line". Difference.

Comment: From what you said CR/LF is not an empty line because it has CR before LF and you treat empty lines only as LF. Check my edited answer and try to make same timing with `Regex`.

Comment: I said "non new line characters". Read carefully please. And are you seriously trying to compare answers based on performance? The OP did not mention performance, he wanted a solution with regular expression. You do not know what he needs it for, maybe it is for a school assignment or he's just curious about regular expressions and is trying to learn them. :)

Comment: He never mentioned that he wanted Regex answer. He just showed that he tried with it. That was the main reason why I haven't made answer with Regex and a bit of performance wise.

Comment: Well, there is a "regex" tag on the question, one can only assume that regular expression is expected. Poorly asked question then. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
`string input = "your text here";`
`string reg = @"([a-zA-Z]+\r\n)+";`
`var m = (text, reg, RegexOptions.Multiline);`

Comment: That's the same regular expression that OP said is not working for him.